# Data Model Standard for Health Insurance companies -- akin to HL7

Tags: data-modeling

Quick question: is anyone aware of an off-the-shelf data model to support the health insurance business? I started reading about HL7, but this seems to pertain to hospital and providers operations, although I could be wrong.

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is covered by EDI transactions that are specific to healthcare/insurance.  North America uses the ANSI ASC X12 standard.

A quick list of Health/Insurance related transactions can be found here: [Insurance/Health Series (INS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X12_Document_List#Insurance.2FHealth_Series_.28INS.29).

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://eligibleapi.com/ - their API will like it will provide what you are looking for, but with a RESTful service behind it (so it's more than just the semantics you may get for HL7) - even if you are just looking for modeling, it's worth checking out.